# Is variance good or bad

Tags: variance, pca

I am learning principal component analysis (PCA). Based on PCA the interesting dynamic occurs along the dimension where the variance is maximized. There is also the notion of signal to noise ratio based on which if the variance of data is much more than that of noise, then we have high quality data.
Imagine we want to measure the length of one particular species of fish. As I understood, a higher variance in our data is good and that the sample is a good representative of the actual size distribution.
However, if we measure the length of a single fish multiple times, then a high variance is bad because it shows there is too much noise in our measurements.

I cannot put these two together. Is variance good or bad? or perhaps the variance of a sample size is good if it is high and the variance of a repeated measurement is bad if it is too high?

Comment: It of course depends on the application and what you want to achieve. Also the point of PCA and related methods is not to "maximize variance" but to explain as much of the variance in the data as possible.

Comment: This is to broad, maybe you can reformulate to concentrate on a specific example you do not understand? Variance is just a measure, it is not good or bad inn itself, depends on your goal!